# Change a sprites color to white (Change brightness)

Tags: android, andengine

Is there a way to change the color of a sprite to white? Changing the color to white does not do anything. Note: I am using GLES2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way. The only way to change color implemented is through Entitiy.setColor(). All color values are multiplied times the pixel's initial value, and value checked for being less than one. So you can tint to a color, but not make it any brighter.

However, making an all white version of your sprite texture is a simple task, and changing the texture dynamicly when needed is pretty simple. So even though this features is not in andengine, it need not change your design.

Incidentally - any white texture in andengine can be tinted to any RGB color. But any black texure will not change color at all.

Comment: I would like to avoid loading another texture that is the same as the original but just white. That seems like it could inflate the size of the game. I am trying to see if there is a way to manually set the color of each pixel in the texture(in andengine) with no success.

Comment: Right. there is not a way to do that within the existing code base of andengine. You would have to write your own implementation. That means getting your hands dirty with openGL like so:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559394/opengl-es-how-to-tint-texture-with-color

Answer (score 0):

What about using the shaders as somebody suggested in the forums?

http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/changing-a-sprite-s-color-to-white-t12114.html#p51903

Not sure if that qualifies as "within the existing code base of andengine". But using shaders it should be possible not only to change the sprite to white but to change the brightness as much as you need.

Comment: Do you have a working example? I've tried what was suggested in that thread with no success.